# For an endomorphism $f:V\to V$ the set of fixed points of $f$ is defined as Fix($f$) $= \{v\in V:f(v)=v\}$ Show Fix$(f)\subseteq V$ is subspace of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions, vector-spaces, vectors

For an endomorphism $f: V \to V$ the set of fixed points of $f$ is defined as Fix($f$) $= \{ v \in V: f(v) = v \} $

Show that Fix($f$) $\subseteq V$ is a subspace of $V$.

---

To be a subspace, we must have the zero vector. As far as I know, the zero vector is always a fixed point because $f(0) = 0$.

We also need to have that it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.
After reading on Wikipedia, it seems an endomorphism is linear. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endomorphism

That means we can use $f(v + u) = f(v) + f(u)$ because as said it is a linear map. If it is linear, we can also use $f(\alpha v) = \alpha f(v)$. Because they are fixed points, we have $f(v) = v, f(u) = u$.

So we have $f(v + u) = f(v) + f(u) = v + u$ and $f(\alpha v) = \alpha f(v) = \alpha v$. So $v + u$ and $\alpha v$ are also fixed points, so it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Is this correct ? I need your feedback because we have no solutions so I have no idea if what I did is even correct

EDIT: I was actually especially unsure about the endomorphism part. Because if we use the linear property of endomorphism, then this seems too easy. We are basically just referring to a property of the function, it seems to me we aren't directly proving something. I should have highlighted that step better. But it is now clear with the answer and comments. Thank you.

Comment: "Endomorphism" means "homomorphism from the structure to itself." In the case of vector spaces, an "endomorphism" means "a linear transformation from the vector space to itself" (also called a "linear operator on $V$").

Comment: Please note that this is not meant to be a "here's my proof, tell me if it is correct" site. If you have specific doubts about a step in your argument, you need to highlight that step and explain why you are doubtful; or if you do not understand a step then you need to specify that step and explain why you do not understand it. Otherwise, the question amounts to asking whether each and every step is correct, and that means there are multiple questions in the post and as such is inappropraite ("Needs more focus").

Comment: @ArturoMagidin This wasn't my intent, sorry. I was actually especially unsure about the endomorphism part. Because if we use the linear property of endomorphism, then this seems too easy. We are basically just referring to a property of the function, we aren't directly proving something. I should have highlighted that step better. Maybe I should have formulated the question "Can we just use the linear property of an endomorphism to show this set of fixed points is closed under addition and scalar multiplication ? Or is this not possible ?". I will keep this in mind for future questions

Comment: Please put the relevant information in the post, not buried in the comments.

Comment: "We are basically just referring to a property of the function, it seems to me we aren't directly proving something." All proofs are like that. We always have to use the given properties of the objects we are working with. If we can't use "properties" of something, then what *can* we use? Properties of objects are the only thing we can work with at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, what you did is correct.

You can save a tiny bit of work by noticing that to check that a subset is a subspace, it is enough to check that $u+\alpha v$ is in the subspace for every $u,v$ in the subset and every scalar $\alpha$. This already implies the fact that the subset contains $0$ and it puts together both steps you did.  That said, as walkar correctly comments, one needs to show that that the subset is nonempty, and an easy way to do so is often checking that it contains $0$.

So a full argument would be: let $u,v\in\operatorname{fix(f)}$ and $\alpha$ a scalar. Then
$$
f(u+\alpha v)=f(u)+\alpha f(v)=u+\alpha v, 
$$
using first the linearity of $f$ and then that $u,v$ are fixed points. So $\operatorname{fix}(f)$ is a subspace of $V$.

Comment: A minor point: one does need to prove that the set is nonempty to use that $u+\alpha v$ is in the set implies it is a subspace, so your third sentence is not quite right. This is often most easily done by showing $0$ is in the set anyway, but certainly it is true that once one knows that the set is nonempty, it immediately implies that $0$ is in the set.

Comment: Very good point. I have edited that in.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\text{Fix}(f)=\text{ker}(f-id_V)$. Hence it is a subspace.